# different reaction to collision on node using sprite kit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, angle, rectangles

I have rectangle shape paddle node, **my question is - is it possible to "cut" node in half so when, for example ball, hit right side of node ball will go back with bigger angle, that it came, and same thing on other side.** Im bad with words so, here are image of what I want to do :[image: Image of what I want to do]

For paddle node i use this code:

```
paddle = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithImageNamed: @"board.png"];
paddle.name = paddleCategoryName;
paddle.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.origin.x + 50, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
[self addChild:paddle];
paddle.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:paddle.frame.size];
paddle.physicsBody.restitution = 0.1f;
paddle.physicsBody.friction = 0.4f;
paddle.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
```

and for ball :

```
ball = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed: @"ball.png"];
[self addChild:ball];
ball.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:ball.size.width];
ball.physicsBody.friction = 0.0f;
ball.physicsBody.restitution = 1.0f;
ball.physicsBody.linearDamping = 0.0f;
ball.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
```

Comment: i haven't seen it done that way (splitting a sprite and adding two different collision to two side of it) why don't you split that sprite by creating two sprites and place them next to each other and create their movement to be identical in touch category and give them separate collision categories. maybe that will work. it is a work around but with the desired result.

Comment: Why not use didBeginContact and didEndContact and examine where about on the paddle the ball hit. Then add an impulse to the ball in the appropriate direction so that the rebound angle appears larger?